# How to paste the contens of a text file including foreign characters

Tags: c, file, encoding

I'm trying to read a .txt file with UTF-8 encoding and paste it's contents to a
string so I can parse it later.

The issue is the copied contents aren't correct. Non-English characters are not only read wrong, but they are also copied as 2 or more random characters onto the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <locale.h>
void main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");
    FILE *dosya = fopen("InsertFilePath", "r");
    char yazi[1000];
    char c;
    yazi[0] = '\0';
    fseek(dosya, 0, SEEK_SET);
    while((c = fgetc(dosya)) != EOF)
            {
                strncat(yazi, &c, 1);
            }
    printf("%s", yazi);
}
```

this code prints out:

```
Nesneye YÃ¶nelik Programlama TÃ¼rkÃ§e Karakter
```

instead of:

```
Nesneye Yönelik Programlama Türkçe Karakter
```

As the troublesome characters in question are Turkish I put this line in the code: `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Turkish");`

Though, it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: This is probably an issue with the terminal you're running the program in, NOT the program itself.   I just compiled your program exactly as written, copied + pasted the sample string into "InsertFilePath" and saved as UTF-8 text file in VIM, ran the test program and got the expected output.

Comment: Also `'LC_ALL, "Turkish"` may not be a valid locale on many operating systems. But also setting locale doesn't change terminal settings, so see first comment

Comment: Are you sure that the characters are being read out of the file wrong, or is the terminal simply unable to display certain UTF-8 characters? The fancy-non-ASCII characters have multi-byte UTF-8 representations that are likely just confusing `printf` and/or the console

Comment: The code snippet given in the post is declared as a separate function in the actual project I am working on. There, I also need to copy the FILE NAME as in "Türkçe.txt" and got the same problem with Turkish characters. The intruiging part is LC_ALL, "Turkish" line actually solves the problem in the main function for the file names but not the reading operation done on a seperate function. Also, I am working on CodeBlocks GNU GCC Compiler.

Comment: Also have to mention that when I try to compare file name(excluding the extension) and copied string from the text file, it says the two strings are not identical.

Comment: Please add important new information by [edit]ing your question. Down here in the comments they will be overseen. You might want to describe exactly what you mean by your last comments, including providing the file's contents, the command lines and their output.